# How to convert pandas series to simple interger

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to get 1347 as integer from the following series. I am using pandas with python.

```
Int64Index([1347], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: `pd.Int64Index([1347], dtype='int64').values[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much that definitely did the trick

Answer (score 0):

`pd.Int64Index([your list], dtype='int64').values[your index]`